# Which sentence is correct--tense and 'while' problem?

Tags: tense

> 1. Our ticket queue has been backed up while we **work** through the hardware
>      issues that **has taken place**.
> 2. Our ticket queue has been backed up while we **have worked** through the hardware issues that **taken the place**.
> 3. Our ticket queue has been backed up while the hardware issues we **work** through **has taken place**.

Comment: Example 1 is best, although *issues* is plural, and requires the plural *have* instead of the singular *has*.

Comment: "Our ticket queue has been backed up" literally is a completed action. Did you mean "Our ticket queue has been *backing* up"?

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the issue here that makes it difficult - difficult to answer as well as hard for you to work it out for yourself - is that ***back up*** has several meanings.

The case you hear most about computers means "to make a copy (of whatever) in case something happens to the original". In this case, that would mean someone made a copy of the ticket queue, presumably of the database, in case something went wrong with the hardware issues and what was done to resolve them.

That seems less likely to me than the second alternative here, though it's certainly plausible. Another meaning of *back up* is for a long queue to develop (or similar things in different context - you would say *the drains are backed up* if they were blocked and taking a long time to empty). In that case, it would mean that the ticket queue has grown much faster than it could be cleared, during the hardware issues.

However, the grammar is similar either way. You seem a little confused between tenses, combinations of tenses, and possibly just the use of appropriate words. I'm going to give you a solution, with explanation, but I've had to make assumptions about the situation.

I am assuming that there have been hardware issues, that people have been working to resolve them, but that this has meant that the ticket system has ended up very full of tickets waiting to be handled. I am assuming that the problem is still ongoing, though I'll provide an alternative at the end of this answer for the case where the hardware problems have been resolved but the ticket system still has a lot of tickets left to be handled, so support is being slower than usual. I'm also assuming that this is for a notice or apology about support being slower than usual. I'm using your choice of words - at least the major verbs and nouns - wherever possible. I'll suggest some alternative choices of words as I explain the version I've written.

> Our ticket queue has **become backed up** while we **work through** the hardware issues **that have taken place**.

*Backed up* is a state, an adjectival phrase based on the past participle of *to back*. You could say that is *is backed up*, but as you're saying it's related to the hardware issues it's appropriate to use words that indicate it entering that state. *To become* is a good verb for that. I used the present perfect because the queue is presumably already in a state we would call "backed up"; if it were rapidly growing but not that bad yet, you could say *is becoming*.

The simple present of *work* has been used in *work through* because it is happening now, and it is simply more natural in this case than the progressive *are working through* would be. I'm not sure I can give a clear reason why, and there isn't always a good reason that one tense is more idiomatic than another. You might also use "work to resolve" or "work on resolving* instead of work through, to make clear that you are attempting to fix things. I would recommend that change, but it's probably a matter of opinion as to which is better.

While I am assuming that you are still working to resolve the hardware issues, I assume that the actual underlying incident - say, a disk failure - has happened. While the effects are still being felt, there is not an ongoing situation where issues are developing. That means the present perfect *have taken place* is appropriate. It is *have* rather than *has* because *issues* is plural. You might also choose the simpler "have happened" or more formal "have occurred", or "we have experienced" if you want to make it more personal.

If the hardware problems have now been resolved, but there's still a lot of tickets to sort out, then the tenses change a little:

> Our ticket system **became** backed up while we **were working through** the hardware issues **that took place**.

The simple past tense for *become* is used because it is less associated with present events than in the other version. However, *has become* is not incorrect in this instance, and could still be used if you prefer it. That happened during the time that work was being done, and that time is in the past, so the past progressive is most appropriate. Finally, *take place* shifts to simple past for the same reasons as *become*.

Comment: you said *"someone made a copy of **the ticket queue**, presumably of **the database**"*. I am very curious to know why you used the definite article there. You didn't have a specific ticket queue or database in mind, did you?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko There's a specific ticket queue referred to in the question. I don't know anything about it, but it's specific, hence *the* for *ticket queue*. Most ticket queue software is database-driven, so will have a database behind it. I specifically mean the database behind this ticket queue, so it's another *the* for *database*.